# Finding measurements of unknown points relative to reference points with known lat, long and measurements?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I am trying to measurements of the distance of multiple points relative to reference points of known latitude, longitude and measurements along a river.

Is there tool that can do this?

Would dynamic segmentation or linear reference work to able to see the measurements in the attribute table?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but I would recommend you look at [Point Distance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001r000000).

Comment: Have a look into the linear referencing tools.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Fezter.  What you are describing sounds like **[Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003900000001000000)**:

> Many organizations collect data about linear features as point
>   locations along the line as an alternative to expressing the locations
>   using x,y coordinates.

In particular you may want to look at the [Calibrate Routes (Linear Referencing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003m00000004000000) tool:

> Recalculates route measures using points.